# React Native: Is there a Debugger Menu Item Like Component to use? (iOS/AppleTV)

Tags: ios, react-native, tvos

I wonder if there is a built in component in React Native that let's me create "native" system-default buttons like the one used in the Debugger Menu? I'm building for Apple TV but a default iOS one is appreciated too.

I have searched in the documentation but the closest I could find is the ActionSheetIOS which is not this menu.

[image: Debugger Menu]

Answer (score 2):

This is how Alerts look like on tvOS.

The RN developer menu uses a `UIAlertController` to show the available actions, and the `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet` style is used for the "phone" idiom and `UIAlertControllerStyleAlert` for all other idioms including TV.

So to achieve this look on tvOS you should use `AlertIOS`. On iOS it will obviously look different.

Comment: Thanks, I was specifically asking for the menu items because I wanted to use them in a replicate of the "catalog" template (used in Movies and Music for example) for the sidebar menu. Afaik there is not component to use for them in React Native so I tried to rebuild them with a `TouchableHighlight` component.

Comment: So I don't know what you're looking for exactly. The RN developer menu on tvOS is using the native `UIAlertController` with the alert style and it is available via `AlertIOS`